# Setting the mouse hover preview variable sensitivity when using the debugger for c++

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-debugger, mousehover

When I single step using c++ (using macosx lldb), and hover over an object variable to preview the contents, the box pops open but most times it just closes before I have a chance to drill down on the object.  Is there a setting to make it where it just stays there until the mouse cursor moves outside the box? I don't know if this setting is it.

```
// Enable value preview when cursor is hovering over a variable.
  "lldb.evaluateForHovers": true,
```

[image: See example of hovering below]

Comment: would a shortcut to trigger the popup at the current cursor location be a sufficient solution ?

Comment: The mouse hover quick preview is the speediest. Looking for a fix for that.